# Windows 10 Slite Not working

Tags: c#, sqlite, cordova, windows-runtime, windows-10-universal

I am trying to integrate sqlite in my windows 10 cordova application. Created a windows runtime component and added reference of

[image]

invoking the runtime component method from the javascript.
`var db = new WinRuntime.Database();`

Getting exception in the run time.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.

Trying out for last one week but no answer. Any thing would be helful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a basic demo and reproduced this problem. It seems that the project failed to find the assembly of SQLite.

Currently the workaround is to add the dll files manually. You need to add the following two dll files:

1. **C:\Users\.nuget\packages\SQLite.Net-PCL\\lib\portable-win8+net45+wp8+wpa81+MonoAndroid1+MonoTouch1\SQLite.Net.dll**
2. **C:\Users\.nuget\packages\SQLite.Net-PCL\\lib\Windows8\SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.dll**

And don't forget to uninstall the `SQLite.Net-PCL` package in your project.